# How do I find the App Bundle Path from within the info.plist file?

Tags: xcode, macos, frameworks, info.plist

I have a custom version of the WebKit framework that I store in my app bundle.  I would like to override the Environmental Variable DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH to look inside my app bundle.  I am using the info.plist file to do this.  If I give it an absolute path to my custom WebKit framework everything works perfectly, but this doesn't do me any good since a user can move the app bundle around which would break the absolute path.  Is there a way to retrieve the current location of the app bundle inside the info.plist file, for instance with a another environmental variable?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Couldn't you put a relative path into DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH? As long as it always resolves to the custom WebKit framework, you should be okay.

Comment: Where does the info.plist file directory start from, I tried ./Frameworks, ./Contents/Frameworks?

Comment: As Info.plist is in the same directory as your embedded `Frameworks` directory, then it should just be `Frameworks`.

Comment: My info.plist is in the directory as the Frameworks folder, but this didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

"@executable_path/../Frameworks" didn't work, how about

$(EXECUTABLE_PATH)/../Frameworks

this will also depend on your install directory of your custom framework, which should be referenced the same way or with the @rpath path.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work.  My framework has the install name of @executable_path/../Frameworks

Comment: That comes out to "Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks" which won't work, I need it to translate from a relative at a absolute path.  I need it to be flexible for I don't know where the app bundle will be.  I am starting to think this is not possible from the plist.